# Receiving a compile error in Excel VBA trying to insert excel formula into range

Tags: excel, vba

I'm getting a compile error on the following line of VBA code

```
Range("D2:D" & LastRow).Formula = "=IFERROR(TRIM(MID(C2,FIND("(",C2)+1,256)),"")"
```

It seems to not like the "(" in the Find statement but this is the formula I want to use in the cell. What is going on here? The formula works fine in excel. I want all the text following the "(" occurrence in the string.

Comment: The normal approach is to double up all the inner quotes in the string, so `"=IFERROR(TRIM(MID(C2,FIND(""("",C2)+1,256)),"""")"`.